# Plupload filters to allow all but a few extensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

Pupload lets you specify which file types can be uploaded, but I want to do the opposite: Allow all filetypes except a certain subset. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a solution on Plupload's Github. You have to use the `addFileFilter` method.

```
    plupload.addFileFilter('excluded_extensions', function(filter, file, cb){
        var permitted = true;
        var exts = filter[0].extensions.split(',');
        //We have no excluded extensions, function presented default exclusion string, so allow anything
        if(exts.length === 1 && exts[0] === "-")
            permitted = true;
        else
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < exts.length; i++)
            {
                var fileArray = file.name.split('.');
                var extension = fileArray[fileArray.length - 1];

                if(exts[i].toUpperCase() === extension.toUpperCase())
                {
                    this.trigger('Error', {
                        code: plupload.FILE_EXTENSION_ERROR,
                        message: plupload.translate('File extension error.'),
                        file: file
                    });
                    permitted = false;
                    cb(false);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if(permitted)
            cb(true);
    });
```

[Source](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/issues/1242)